# Issues reproducing reversible CA from NKS

Tags: cellular-automata

I want to recreate the output of the reversible cellular automaton described in [this page](https://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-437) of the NKS book.

[image]

The book specifies that this is a modified version of R214, where the new state (step+1) is inverted if state of the cell at step-1 is 1.

R214 is specified as:
[image]

I realized that this inversion can be accomplished using a BitXor between the states computed by R214 for step +1 and the state of the lattice at step-1, so I wrote the following code:

```
steps = 100;

spaceTimeRandIC = 
CellularAutomaton[rule = 214, 
  initialCondition = RandomInteger[1, 500], steps];

spaceTimeRevRandIC = Table[
  BitXor[spaceTimeRandIC[[i - 1]], 
  spaceTimeRandIC[[i + 1]]], 
  {i, 2, steps, 1}
 ];

totalEvolRandIC = Join[{spaceTimeRandIC[[1]]}, spaceTimeRevRandIC];
ArrayPlot[totalEvolRandIC]
```

Which produces an output that lacks the reversibility of the example:
[image]

**Question: where did I go wrong here?**

PS: I've been checking S. Wolfram's [programs for this section](http://www.wolframscience.com/nks/programs/NKSPrograms-09.nb), and I have a hard time understanding them. They were apparently written before the existence of the CellularAutomaton function. How the Mod, RotateLeft, and RotateRight functions influence the evolution of the CA escapes me.